# How do I send custom property to receiver end in Outlook addin?

Tags: c#, vba, outlook-addin

I am using Outlook 16 and I created an Addin in VSTO.

I created a separate region in Appointment there I added a drop-down. I want to send the selected drop-down value with that region to receiver side.

I installed this addin on the system, but the drop-down value is not getting what I selected here.

I am adding Property on both way `UserProperty` and in Header. It saves local, but at receiver end it is not showing.

```
private void ItemSend_Send(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    try
    {
        Outlook.UserProperty _activityTrackertyoe = app_Item.UserProperties.Add("ActivityTrackerType", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText,true, 1);
        _activityTrackertyoe.Value = ActivityTrackerType.Text;
        Outlook.UserProperty _subType = app_Item.UserProperties.Add("ActivityTrackerSubType", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText,true, 1);
        _subType.Value = ActivityTrackerSubType.Text;
        app_Item.Body = ActivityTrackerType.Text + "<<<->>>>" + ActivityTrackerSubType.Text;
        app_Item.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/X-{ActivityTrackerType}", ActivityTrackerType.Text);
        app_Item.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/X-{ActivityTrackerSubType}", ActivityTrackerSubType.Text);
        app_Item.Save();
        app_Item.Display();
        app_Item.Send();
        MessageBox.Show("Sent"+ _activityTrackertyoe.Value+"sub"+ _subType.Value);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

It sends, but not with `UserPropery`.

Answer (score 0):

You are **not** setting a property on the outgoing meetign request (`Item`), you are setting the property on some other item (`app_Item`).

You need to cast the outgoing Item parameter as `MeetingItem` to check that you really have a meeting request, retrieve the corresponding `AppointmentItem` using `MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment`, copy the property from `AppointmentItem` to `MeetingItem`.

You should not call `Display` and `Send` (which make no sense, especially whne used together).